# How to know which users/nodes failed to import in feeds logs?

Tags: users, feeds

I'm trying to convert my implementation from the location to geofield modules. Not finding an easy way to convert the data, I tried the manual way which is to export the data to CSV and then repopulate the appropriate fields through fields. The issue is I have a lot of users, around a 1000, and the feeds log is just telling me that 44 of them failed. Is there anyway to know which ones failed? The feeds log doesn't give me a lot of diagnostic information, and manually checking is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

So views data export will truncate some user names based on their lengths. This resulted in a mismatch between the exported users' name and the user name in the DB, leading to errors.